# How to fit table on a page using \supertabular in latex?

Tags: tables, supertabular

I am running this code. It formats the second page not the first. How do I fit the first page like the second. Please help!

```
\begin{supertabular}{|p{7.215em}|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .8,  .565} \multicolumn{7}{|p{46.93em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{State-wise Storage Capacity and Number of }}} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .8,  .565} \multicolumn{7}{|p{46.93em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Godowns Available with FCI in India}}} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .8,  .565} \multicolumn{7}{|p{46.93em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{(As on 30.06.2009)}}} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .89,  .906} \textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{States/UTs}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{8.93em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{No. of Godowns (Covered)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.5em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Storage Capacity (Covered) (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.5em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{No. of Godowns (CAP)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.285em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Storage Capacity (CAP) (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.715em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Total Number of Godowns (Covered and CAP (Provisional)}}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.785em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Total Capacity (Covered and CAP (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} \\
    \midrule
    Bihar & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}50 & 5.65  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.43  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}53 & 6.08 \\
    \midrule
    Jharkhand & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}19 & 1.16  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}19 & 1.16 \\
    \midrule
    Orissa & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}77 & 6.58  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}77 & 6.58 \\
    \midrule
    West Bengal & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}43 & 10.57 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}43 & 10.57 \\
    \midrule
    Sikkim & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.11  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.11 \\
    \midrule
    Assam & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 2.74  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 2.74 \\
    \midrule
    Arunachal Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 0.21  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 0.21 \\
    \midrule
    Meghalaya & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.26  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.26 \\
    \midrule
    Mizoram & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.23  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.23 \\
    \midrule
    Tripura & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 0.49  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 0.49 \\
    \midrule
    Manipur & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.2   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.2 \\
    \midrule
    Nagaland & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.32  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0.32  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.32 \\
    \midrule
    Delhi & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 3.36  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.34  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 3.4 \\
    \midrule
    Haryana & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}115 & 19.91 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}30 & 3.28  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}145 & 23.19 \\
    \midrule
    Himachal Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}17 & 0.25  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}17 & 0.25 \\
    \midrule
    Jammu and Kashmir & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}26 & 1.29  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}26 & 1.29 \\
    \midrule
    Punjab & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}259 & 60.56 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}113 & 9.89  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}372 & 70.45 \\
    \midrule
    Chandigarh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}11 & 1.06  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}9 & 0.22  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}20 & 1.28 \\
    \midrule
    Rajasthan & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}104 & 13.35 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}21 & 3.22  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}125 & 16.57 \\
    \midrule
    Uttar Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}115 & 21.99 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}30 & 4.89  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}145 & 26.78 \\
    \midrule
    Uttranchal & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}20 & 2.07  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.3   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}24 & 2.37 \\
    \midrule
    Andhra Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}168 & 34.48 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 2.62  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}175 & 37.1 \\
    \midrule
    Andaman and Nicobar Islands & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.07  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.07 \\
    \midrule
    Kerala & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}23 & 5.17  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.2   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}28 & 5.37 \\
    \midrule
    Karnataka & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}64 & 6.16  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}9 & 1.36  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}73 & 7.52 \\
    \midrule
    Tamil Nadu & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}28 & 9.04  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.53  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}32 & 9.57 \\
    \midrule
    Pondicherry & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.51  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.05  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}8 & 0.56 \\
    \midrule
    Gujarat & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}27 & 5.86  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.27  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 6.13 \\
    \midrule
    Maharashtra & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}67 & 17.19 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.92  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}71 & 18.11 \\
    \midrule
    Goa   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.15  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.15 \\
    \midrule
    Madhya Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}121 & 8.39  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.35  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}125 & 8.74 \\
    \midrule
    Chhattisgarh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}61 & 7.44  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}61 & 7.44 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{India} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{1501} & \textbf{246.82} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{255} & \textbf{28.77} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{1756} & \textbf{275.59} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{supertabular}%
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Pease turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), especially including the documentclass and possible margin settings. Without this it is nearly impossible for others to help you. Apart from that: Vertical lines are not compatible with `booktabs`'s horizontal rules. Additionally, you might want to rethink the usage of all thouse lines and the colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE that corrects your code to automatically fit the table to the current textwidth.

Changes in comparison to the original code:

- Removed superfluous `multicolumn` commands for the first table row.
- Introduced a new column type `A` with the help of the packages `calc` and `ragged2e`. The widths of these columns are calculated relative to the current `linewidth` (`\tabcolsep` equals the padding that is added on the left and right of every column, `\arrayrulewidth`  equals the width of the vertical lines).
- Switched from `supertabular` to `longtable` as the former didn't seem to allow to calculate column widths.

Please note, that since no documentclass was specified in the original question, I simply chose one that might not meet your requirements.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{(\linewidth-7.215em-14\tabcolsep-(8\arrayrulewidth))/6}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7.215em}|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .8,  .565} \multicolumn{7}{|p{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{State-wise Storage Capacity and Number of  Godowns Available with FCI in India (As on 30.06.2009)}}} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .89,  .906} \textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{States/UTs}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{No. of Godowns (Covered)}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Storage Capacity (Covered) (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{No. of Godowns (CAP)}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Storage Capacity (CAP) (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Total Number of Godowns (Covered and CAP (Provisional)}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .392,  .376}{\textbf{Total Capacity (Covered and CAP (Fig. in Lakh MTs)}}} \\
    \midrule
    Bihar & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}50 & 5.65  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.43  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}53 & 6.08 \\
    \midrule
    Jharkhand & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}19 & 1.16  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}19 & 1.16 \\
    \midrule
    Orissa & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}77 & 6.58  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}77 & 6.58 \\
    \midrule
    West Bengal & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}43 & 10.57 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}43 & 10.57 \\
    \midrule
    Sikkim & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.11  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.11 \\
    \midrule
    Assam & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 2.74  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 2.74 \\
    \midrule
    Arunachal Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 0.21  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 0.21 \\
    \midrule
    Meghalaya & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.26  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.26 \\
    \midrule
    Mizoram & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.23  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.23 \\
    \midrule
    Tripura & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 0.49  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 0.49 \\
    \midrule
    Manipur & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.2   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}3 & 0.2 \\
    \midrule
    Nagaland & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.32  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0.32  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.32 \\
    \midrule
    Delhi & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 3.36  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.34  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}10 & 3.4 \\
    \midrule
    Haryana & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}115 & 19.91 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}30 & 3.28  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}145 & 23.19 \\
    \midrule
    Himachal Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}17 & 0.25  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}17 & 0.25 \\
    \midrule
    Jammu and Kashmir & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}26 & 1.29  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}26 & 1.29 \\
    \midrule
    Punjab & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}259 & 60.56 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}113 & 9.89  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}372 & 70.45 \\
    \midrule
    Chandigarh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}11 & 1.06  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}9 & 0.22  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}20 & 1.28 \\
    \midrule
    Rajasthan & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}104 & 13.35 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}21 & 3.22  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}125 & 16.57 \\
    \midrule
    Uttar Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}115 & 21.99 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}30 & 4.89  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}145 & 26.78 \\
    \midrule
    Uttranchal & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}20 & 2.07  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.3   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}24 & 2.37 \\
    \midrule
    Andhra Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}168 & 34.48 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}7 & 2.62  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}175 & 37.1 \\
    \midrule
    Andaman and Nicobar Islands & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.07  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.07 \\
    \midrule
    Kerala & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}23 & 5.17  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}5 & 0.2   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}28 & 5.37 \\
    \midrule
    Karnataka & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}64 & 6.16  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}9 & 1.36  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}73 & 7.52 \\
    \midrule
    Tamil Nadu & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}28 & 9.04  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.53  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}32 & 9.57 \\
    \midrule
    Pondicherry & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.51  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}2 & 0.05  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}8 & 0.56 \\
    \midrule
    Gujarat & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}27 & 5.86  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}6 & 0.27  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}33 & 6.13 \\
    \midrule
    Maharashtra & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}67 & 17.19 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.92  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}71 & 18.11 \\
    \midrule
    Goa   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.15  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}1 & 0.15 \\
    \midrule
    Madhya Pradesh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}121 & 8.39  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}4 & 0.35  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}125 & 8.74 \\
    \midrule
    Chhattisgarh & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}61 & 7.44  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}0 & 0     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}61 & 7.44 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{India} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{1501} & \textbf{246.82} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{255} & \textbf{28.77} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .847,  .659}\textbf{1756} & \textbf{275.59} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Although the table fits onto the page horizontally, there are still issues concerning the incompatibility of `booktabs` with both vertical rules (interruptions) and colored cells (additional white space around them). I would therefor suggest the following more minimal layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{(\linewidth-2.2cm-14\tabcolsep)/6}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
  \item[*] Fig. in Lakh MTs
  \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{R{2.2cm}
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=4]
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=3.2]
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=3]
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=2.2]
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=4]
                  S[detect-weight,table-format=3.2]}
    \caption{State-wise Storage Capacity and Number of Godowns Available with FCI in India (As on 30.06.2009)}\\    
    \toprule
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Covered}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAP}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Covered and CAP}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    States/UTs & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{No. of Godowns} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Storage Capacity\tnote{*}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{No. of Godowns} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Storage Capacity\tnote{*}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Total No. of Godowns } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Total Capacity\tnote{*}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead%\\
    \toprule
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Covered}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAP}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Covered and CAP}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    States/UTs & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{No. of Godowns} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Storage Capacity\tnote{*}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{No. of Godowns} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Storage Capacity\tnote{*}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Total No. of Godowns } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{P}{Total Capacity\tnote{*}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
    \endfoot
    Bihar &  50 & 5.65  &  3 & 0.43  &  53 & 6.08 \\

    Jharkhand &  19 & 1.16  &  0 & 0     &  19 & 1.16 \\

    Orissa &  77 & 6.58  &  0 & 0     &  77 & 6.58 \\

    West Bengal &  43 & 10.57 &  0 & 0     &  43 & 10.57 \\
    \midrule
    Sikkim &  2 & 0.11  &  0 & 0     &  2 & 0.11 \\

    Assam &  33 & 2.74  &  0 & 0     &  33 & 2.74 \\

    Arunachal Pradesh &  10 & 0.21  &  0 & 0     &  10 & 0.21 \\

    Meghalaya &  6 & 0.26  &  0 & 0     &  6 & 0.26 \\
    \midrule
    Mizoram &  6 & 0.23  &  0 & 0     &  6 & 0.23 \\

    Tripura &  7 & 0.49  &  0 & 0     &  7 & 0.49 \\

    Manipur &  3 & 0.2   &  0 & 0     &  3 & 0.2 \\

    Nagaland &  5 & 0.32  &  0 & 0.32  &  5 & 0.32 \\
    \midrule
    Delhi &  6 & 3.36  &  4 & 0.34  &  10 & 3.4 \\

    Haryana &  115 & 19.91 &  30 & 3.28  &  145 & 23.19 \\

    Himachal Pradesh &  17 & 0.25  &  0 & 0     &  17 & 0.25 \\

    Jammu and Kashmir &  26 & 1.29  &  0 & 0     &  26 & 1.29 \\
    \midrule
    Punjab &  259 & 60.56 &  113 & 9.89  &  372 & 70.45 \\

    Chandigarh &  11 & 1.06  &  9 & 0.22  &  20 & 1.28 \\

    Rajasthan &  104 & 13.35 &  21 & 3.22  &  125 & 16.57 \\

    Uttar Pradesh &  115 & 21.99 &  30 & 4.89  &  145 & 26.78 \\
    \midrule
    Uttranchal &  20 & 2.07  &  4 & 0.3   &  24 & 2.37 \\

    Andhra Pradesh &  168 & 34.48 &  7 & 2.62  &  175 & 37.1 \\

    Andaman and Nicobar Islands &  1 & 0.07  &  0 & 0     &  1 & 0.07 \\

    Kerala &  23 & 5.17  &  5 & 0.2   &  28 & 5.37 \\
    \midrule
    Karnataka &  64 & 6.16  &  9 & 1.36  &  73 & 7.52 \\

    Tamil Nadu &  28 & 9.04  &  4 & 0.53  &  32 & 9.57 \\

    Pondicherry &  6 & 0.51  &  2 & 0.05  &  8 & 0.56 \\

    Gujarat &  27 & 5.86  &  6 & 0.27  &  33 & 6.13 \\
    \midrule
    Maharashtra &  67 & 17.19 &  4 & 0.92  &  71 & 18.11 \\

    Goa   &  1 & 0.15  &  0 & 0     &  1 & 0.15 \\

    Madhya Pradesh &  121 & 8.39  &  4 & 0.35  &  125 & 8.74 \\

    Chhattisgarh &  61 & 7.44  &  0 & 0     &  61 & 7.44 \\
    \midrule
    \bfseries India &  \bfseries 1501  & \bfseries 246.82  &  \bfseries 255 & \bfseries 28.77 &  \bfseries 1756 & \bfseries 275.59 \\
\end{longtable}%
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

The above MWE incorporated the following additional changes:

- Removed all colors (cell backgrounds and text) as well as all vertical and most of the horizontal lines.
- Added some vertical white space (`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`) and few horizontal lines as a guide to the eye.
- Usage of the `siunitx` package to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator.
- Usage of `etoolbox`'s `\robustify` command in corporation with the `detect-weight` option to apply the alignment ot bold numbers as well.
- In order to avoid repetition of information in the table header row, I moved this information in a second row separated by `\cmidrules`.
- Used `\tnote` from the `threeparttablex` package along with the `ThreePartTable` environment and the `\insertTableNotes` command in order to further shorten the table header rows.
- Replaced the first `\multicolumn` command by a `\caption`.
- Using the `\endhead` and `\endfoot` commands from the `longtable` package, I repeated the heading rows on the second page and inserted the footnotes on the bottom of the table on the first and second page.
- ...

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem. I am very grateful!